# Is 'to undefine' something a valid phrase?

Tags: word-usage

I'd like to say: 'My goal is **to undefine** the existing variable.'

I'm using 'to undefine' as opposed to 'to define' phrase. However the dictionary on macOS cannot find the 'undefine' word.

Is this a valid phrase?

Comment: Do you mean set the variable's value to null or its equivalent?

Comment: To do for example: `#undef FOO` (to undefine the property in this case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The verb *undefine* is widespread in computing, especially in programming, where the act of defining something (such as a function, variable, alias or data type) is easy to undo. Many programming languages and command languages have an undefine command (usually as the abbreviated form *undef*).

Comment: In some cases, you'll see _unset_ used similarly.

Comment: @TecBrat and also *undeclare*.